# Magento 2 : How to move sku and instock

Tags: magento-2.1, theme

How to move  sku and instock to down to price in product details page,by default it is coming right side of price but i want it after price

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep below code inside xml file body tag in your xml file,

app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.info.type" destination="alert.urls" before="-"/>
<move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="alert.urls" before="-"/>
```

Comment: not coming Rakesh

Comment: you can check in console in stock and sku are display after price div

Comment: it is coming after div only  before also but not displaying

Comment: i have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks i will check Rakesh, how to move custom options to right i.e size ,color dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Change below code in `Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml` file in your custom theme:

```
<container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review">
                            <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
                                <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </block>
                            </container>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" after="product.info.sku">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                                    <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                                    <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                                </arguments>
                  </block>
  </container>
```

to

```
<container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review">                    
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" after="product.info.sku">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>

<container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
    <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```

Comment: I would never recommend to change the code inside a core module as this will cause issues with any magento updates in future.

Comment: I never said to change this in core module, You need to change this in your custom theme's `Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`